# How did liquidate come to mean murder?

Tags: etymology

To liquidate stocks means converting them into cash. The origin for this expression seems clear enough, because the metaphor of cash as some sort of liquid is quite common and readily understood.

But how about the other meaning of liquidate, which is to murder someone? How did the word acquire that meaning? And why does it carry the specific connotation of murder in a political or organised crime context?

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/liquidate) claims this meaning is informal and comes from the Russian likvidirovat – ликвидировать (eliminate).

Comment: I thought maybe it was from the Wizard of Oz (1939).  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiSyvqw5PTnAhWSv54KHdD5CYgQwqsBMAJ6BAgGEAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-RQxD4Ff7dY&usg=AOvVaw3UWffu-v1d9E-Ck5ERmBc4

Comment: @WeatherVane Lenin and Stalin set as Soviet policy the liquidation of the kulaks (peasants owning 8+ acres of land) , which meant both seizing and redistributing the assets as well as killing the individuals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekulakization

Comment: @user662852 I see, so in that case the two Lexico meanings are one and the same thing!

Comment: The meaning "wipe out, kill" is from 1924, possibly from Russian likvidirovat, ultimately from the Latin word. https://www.etymonline.com/word/liquidate

Comment: Certainly the term has been used in American business for 100 years or so.  And the "businessification" of crime during the 20s could have easily caused the term to be picked up by mobsters.

Answer (score 2):

The term "***liquidate***" dates back to the 16<sup>th</sup> century but its more common contemporary connotations are more recent. As suggested by [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/liquidate), the sense “to kill” probably derives from a Russian usage of the same Latin root.

> 1570s, of accounts, "to reduce to order, to set out clearly" (a sense now obsolete), from Late Latin or Medieval Latin *liquidatus*, past participle of *liquidare* "to melt, make liquid, make clear, clarify," from Latin *liquidus* "fluid, liquid, moist" (see liquid (adj.)). ***Sense of "clear away" (a debt) first recorded 1755.***  ***The meaning "wipe out, kill" is from 1924, possibly from Russian *likvidirovat*, ultimately from the Latin word.***

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidate) also states -

> From Medieval Latin *liquidatus* (“liquid, clear”), past participle of
>   *liquidare*. The sense “to kill, do away with” is a semantic loan from
>   Russian ликвиди́ровать (*likvidírovatʹ*), ultimately from Latin
>   *liquidus*.

The use of *[liquidate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=liquidate&allowed_in_frame=0)* and *[liquidation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=liquidation&allowed_in_frame=0)* as a euphemism for killing or disposing of  “inconvenient groups of persons” dates from about 1924 or 1925, according to the [*etymonline*](https://etymonline.com) entries referenced at the beginning of this sentence.  Those links seem to suggest that *liquidate* in this particular sense may have followed from Russian *likvidirovat*.

Per the OED, it comes from the Russian ликвиди́ровать (*likvidírovatʹ*) -

> **7**. after Russ. *likvidírovat′* to liquidate, wind up. To put an end to, abolish; to stamp out, wipe out; to kill.
>
> - 1924 Yale Rev. XIII. 477 ― In this way the ‘Labor Opposition’, the ‘Workers Pravda’, and a few other recalcitrant groups were all ‘liquidated’.
> - 1926 C. Sheridan Turkish Kaleidoscope xvi. 125 ― The evening paper, L’Akcham, came out with large headlines: ‘How to Liquidate a Strike’.
> - 1930 Economist 1 Nov. (Russ. Suppl.) 2/2 ― Only in 1929, when the growth of the Socialist section of agriculture was enabling the State to become independent of the supplies of the Kulaks, could the Government begin to ‘liquidate’ them.
> - 1939 V. A. Demant Relig. Prospect iv. 90 ― The Trotskyists··are ‘liquidated’ as being insufficiently dialectical to see that the policy of the Russian State at any moment has absolute finality.
> - 1943 C. S. Lewis Abolition of Man iii. 37 ― Once we killed bad men: now we liquidate unsocial elements.
> - 1957 Partridge English gone Wrong ii. 31 ― Liquidate, therefore, is an erudite synonym of ‘to wind up’, hence, in its euphemistic transferred sense, it means ‘to eradicate in a thoroughly ruthless manner’, ‘to destroy, especially by mass murder’.
> - 1970 Nature 26 Dec. 1248/2 ― All existing sources of industrial pollution are to be ‘liquidated’.
> - 1971 Sunday Times 13 June 12/6 ― When the army units fanned out in Dacca on the evening of March 25··many of them carried lists of people to be liquidated.